# How to display estimated normal and save this window in open3d (python)?

Tags: python, open3d

I run into an issue of displaying estimated normal of the points and save this window in jpg.

I know that using "open3d.visualization.draw_geometries(pcd,point_show_normal=True)" allows us to see normal along with pointcloud. However, I am not quite sure how to save this window to jpg.

For example, I would like to save this window (draw_geometries) to jpg.

[screenshot of window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZmxv.png)

Answer (score 1):

As explained in http://www.open3d.org/docs/0.10.0/tutorial/Basic/visualization.html, you can press `P` to capture the screen. It will be saved in the path you run the script as a `png` file.